# How to submit a job to the standalone standalone using sql-cli

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I followed the example in the link below, but got an error
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POJbA.png)

org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Could not execute SQL statement.
at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:208) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeQuery(LocalExecutor.java:228) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callSelect(CliClient.java:542) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callOperation(CliClient.java:446) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeOperation(CliClient.java:372) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.getAndExecuteStatements(CliClient.java:329) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInteractive(CliClient.java:280) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInInteractiveMode(CliClient.java:228) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.openCli(SqlClient.java:151) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:95) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161) [flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:903) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1382) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:206) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterRetrieveException: Couldn't retrieve Yarn cluster
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.retrieve(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:419) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.retrieve(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:139) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.AbstractSessionClusterExecutor.execute(AbstractSessionClusterExecutor.java:80) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2188) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultExecutor.java:95) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:884) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1382) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:206) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Yarn application application_1678676822488_0188 doesn't run anymore.
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.retrieve(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:405) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.retrieve(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:139) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.AbstractSessionClusterExecutor.execute(AbstractSessionClusterExecutor.java:80) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2188) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultExecutor.java:95) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:884) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1382) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:206) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
... 11 more

Comment: Maybe I should manually configure execution.target?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to run Flink SQL Client on **Yarn** because you have an error like : `The Yarn application application_1678676822488_0188 doesn't run anymore`. If so you need to create a Yarn session where you job will run.

Otherwise you can set existing Yarn container in your script: `SET 'yarn.application.id' = 'application_1681806057912_7665';`